# Why the nonce is difficult to find in Bitcoin?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bitcoin, blockchain

I read many articles explain the Bitcoin POW, but every article seems copy form each other. they just indicate find a nonce start from 1, but I still confused why find a nonce number is so difficult? I know the hash value must lower than the target difficulty.

for example:
the Block #500000, the nonce is 1560058197, so this block hash value lower than the target when the nonce equal 1560058197.

if I start from 1 increasing the nonce to 1560058197, that is mean computer doing the SHA256 1560058197 times, that is not that hard for a pool?

1 GHash/s only need take 1 seconds?
did I miss something there?

[Block #500000 from Blockchain.info](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwifi5-q6sTYAhWIfrwKHZICACoQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblockchain.info%2Fblock%2F00000000000000000024fb37364cbf81fd49cc2d51c09c75c35433c3a1945d04&usg=AOvVaw0KI99limcxYBR7ol5rriGn)

Comment: Computing the hash is not very difficult. That's why miners are able to mine a bitcoin every 10 minutes

Comment: Once you run out of nonces, you vary the block contents to change the block root hash and then try another 4 billion nonces.

Comment: When you say why its difficult to find the nonce, do you mean difficult to compute the number? Or do you mean some other part is difficult?

Comment: Precise answer to your question is given here - https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/how-much-time-in-average-does-it-take-for-an-simple-pc-to-create-block

Comment: @ArunGeorge I think the OP's confusion is that there is only a 32-bit nonce, while it takes far more than 2^32 hash computations to match the block difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before I thought it would guarantee to find a nonce when you count 1 to 2^32, but no....there is no guarantee

a friend told me, most of the time the computers run out of nonce count and usually they couldn't find a hash below the target, so they need change the block content then do that again, that's why miners need a bit of luck!